# Pass value from operator to dag

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I have a BashOperator in my dag which runs a python script. At the end of its run, the python script creates a json as a report. In case of failure, I want to report this json to Slack. I have an `on_failure_callback` function which can push a message to Slack. However, I have no elegant way to pass the json value to the dag. Currently, I am saving the json to a file and then reading it from the file in the dag and reporting it.  I also tried storing it in an environment variable and getting it in the dag. But is there a more direct way to pass this value to the dag? Preferably, without saving it to a file or an environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `on_failure_callback` you should use another task to send your slack message.

And for that you should simply use XComs to push/pull the file. https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/xcoms.html#

Then you can pull the xcom in the task that sends it further to slack.